# velX and velY in optical flow (how to add them)

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, opticalflow

I am doing project in Emgu cv in C#.

I have stuck in this first step. I calculated opticalflow.HS and LK and I don't know how to add velx and vely to draw them in frame as points and show them in ImageBox.

```
 OpticalFlow.HS(prev, frame1, true, velx, vely, 0.1d, new MCvTermCriteria(100));
```

Does anyone can describe me what to do or even better some code example will be a lot of help? I don't want to show color of direction, only motion as points in frame.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, so if anyone needs here is my example.

```
         Image<Gray, Byte> coloredMotion2 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(frame1.Size);
          for (int i = 0; i < coloredMotion2.Width; i+=2)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < coloredMotion2.Height; j+=2)
              {
                  dx = (int)CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(velx, j, i);
                  dy = (int)CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(vely, j, i);

                  int pomi = i + dx;
                  int pomj = j + dy;

                  if (i != pomi && j != pomj)
    // uncoment line below if you want lines but it needs rgb image not gray                            {
   //CvInvoke.cvLine(coloredMotion, new Point(i,j),new Point(i+dx,j+dy), new   MCvScalar(255,0,0), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, 0);                          
  CvInvoke.cvCircle(coloredMotion2, new Point(pomi, pomj), 1, new MCvScalar(255,255,255), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, 0); 
                  }
   motionImageBox.Image = coloredMotion2;
```